# Polars query optimization

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars DataFrame with labeled data for which I need to compute a variety of statistics on combinations of the labels.

Here is an example:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [date(2024, 1, 1), date(2024, 1, 2), date(2024, 1, 3)] * 3,
        "label": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 3,
        "value": [1, 4, 2, 1, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    }
)
print(df)
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ label ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ str   ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2024-01-01 ┆ A     ┆ 1     │
│ 2024-01-02 ┆ A     ┆ 4     │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ A     ┆ 2     │
│ 2024-01-01 ┆ B     ┆ 1     │
│ 2024-01-02 ┆ B     ┆ -3    │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ B     ┆ 0     │
│ 2024-01-01 ┆ C     ┆ 1     │
│ 2024-01-02 ┆ C     ┆ 2     │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ C     ┆ 3     │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

I would like to compute the min/max for the separate time-series for `A+B`, `B+C` and `A+C`. What would be the most efficient way to do this with polars?

The result should be:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ literal ┆ min ┆ max │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A+B     ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ A+C     ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ B+C     ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

This is what I have done so far:

```py
lazy_df = df.lazy()

a = lazy_df.filter(pl.col("label") == "A").select("date", a_value=pl.col("value"))
b = lazy_df.filter(pl.col("label") == "B").select("date", b_value=pl.col("value"))
c = lazy_df.filter(pl.col("label") == "C").select("date", c_value=pl.col("value"))

a_b = pl.concat([a, b], how="align").select(pl.lit("A+B"), min=(pl.col("a_value") + pl.col("b_value")).min(), max=(pl.col("a_value") + pl.col("b_value")).max())
a_c = pl.concat([a, c], how="align").select(pl.lit("A+C"), min=(pl.col("a_value") + pl.col("c_value")).min(), max=(pl.col("a_value") + pl.col("c_value")).max())
b_c = pl.concat([b, c], how="align").select(pl.lit("B+C"), min=(pl.col("b_value") + pl.col("c_value")).min(), max=(pl.col("b_value") + pl.col("c_value")).max())

stats_df = pl.concat([a_b, a_c, b_c]).collect()
print(stats_df)
```

This, however, is really quite inefficient especially for large datasets and a large number of aggregations of the labels.

Comment: You can use expressions for your variables without materializing anything e.g. `a = pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("label") == "A")` and write a single select: `.select((a + b).min().alias("A+B_min"), (a + b).max()...)` - but are you also wanting to do this "dynamically" i.e. without manually specifying each combination?

Comment: Yes, this was just a small example. In practice, I am not manually specifying each combination, but I guess this wouldn't really change anything would it? I would just end up with a list of queries? I did also try something along those lines but it was quite slow.

Answer (score 4):

You can join on date, then filter out rows you don't need, then compute the aggs.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [date(2024, 1, 1), date(2024, 1, 2), date(2024, 1, 3)] * 3,
        "label": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 3,
        "value": [1, 4, 2, 1, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    }
).lazy()

df.join(df, how="left", on=pl.col("date")).filter(
    pl.col("label") < pl.col("label_right")
).with_columns(
    value=pl.col("value") + pl.col("value_right"),
    literal=pl.format("{}+{}", pl.col("label"), pl.col("label_right")),
).group_by(
    "literal"
).agg(
    min=pl.col("value").min(), max=pl.col("value").max()
).sort(
    "literal"
).collect()
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ literal ┆ min ┆ max │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A+B     ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ A+C     ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ B+C     ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshape using [`.pivot()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot)

```py
out = df.pivot(values="value", index="date", columns="label")
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ date       ┆ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ date       ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2024-01-01 ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2024-01-02 ┆ 4   ┆ -3  ┆ 2   │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 3   │
└────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Use the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of the resulting columns (minus `date`) to build an expression.

Our expression consists of:

- a List of [Structs](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/) which we `.flatten()` to create separate rows.

```py
import itertools

pairs = itertools.combinations(out.drop("date").columns, r=2)

sums = (
   pl.struct(
      label = pl.lit(f"{L}+{R}"), 
      min = (pl.col(L) + pl.col(R)).min(), 
      max = (pl.col(L) + pl.col(R)).max()
   ) 
   for L, R in pairs
)

sums = pl.concat_list(sums).flatten().alias("sums")
```

```py
>>> sums
# <Expr ['String(A+B).alias("label").as_…'] at 0x12EA14AF0>
```

```py
out.select(sums)
```

```py
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────────────┐
│ sums         │
│ ---          │
│ struct[3]    │
╞══════════════╡
│ {"A+B",1,2}  │
│ {"A+C",2,6}  │
│ {"B+C",-1,3} │
└──────────────┘
```

Which can be turned into individual columns with [`.unnest()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest)

```py
out.select(sums).unnest("sums")
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ label ┆ min ┆ max │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A+B   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ A+C   ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ B+C   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way - how does this do on your benchmark code?

```py
(
    df.lazy()
    .join(df.lazy(), how="cross")
    .with_columns(
        val_sum=pl.col("value") + pl.col("value_right"),
        label_combined=pl.col("label") + pl.col("label_right"),
    )
    .filter(
        pl.col("date") == pl.col("date_right"),
        pl.col("label_combined").is_in(["AB", "AC", "BC"]),
    )
    .group_by("label_combined")
    .agg(
        min=pl.col("val_sum").min(),
        max=pl.col("val_sum").max(),
    )
    .select("label_combined", "min", "max")
    .collect()
)
```

It outputs:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ label_combined ┆ min ┆ max │
│ ---            ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str            ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞════════════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ BC             ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
│ AB             ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ AC             ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
└────────────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without specifying all the combinations. You can first 'join' all the rows with correct date by using [`pivot()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html), and then use [`sum_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sum_horizontal.html) to sum up necessary columns.
Note usage of [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) so you don't have to type it manually.

```
import itertools

df_piv = df.pivot(values='value',index='date',columns='label')
labels = df['label'].unique()
num = 2

def calc(df_calc, l):
    df_calc = df_calc.select(l).sum_horizontal()
    return ['+'.join(sorted(l)), df_calc.min(), df_calc.max()]

res = pl.DataFrame(
    data = [calc(df_piv, l) for l in itertools.combinations(labels, num)],
    schema = ['literal','min','max']
)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ literal ┆ min ┆ max │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A+C     ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ B+C     ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
│ A+B     ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Also, usage of `pivot` allows you to use combinations of 3 and more labels together. For example, let's take a dataframe with 4 different labels:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [date(2024, 1, 1), date(2024, 1, 2), date(2024, 1, 3), date(2024, 1, 4)] * 3,
        "label": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 3 + ["D"] * 3,
        "value": [1, 4, 2, 1, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, -4],
    }
)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ label ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ str   ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2024-01-01 ┆ A     ┆ 1     │
│ 2024-01-02 ┆ A     ┆ 4     │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ A     ┆ 2     │
│ 2024-01-04 ┆ B     ┆ 1     │
│ …          ┆ …     ┆ …     │
│ 2024-01-01 ┆ C     ┆ 3     │
│ 2024-01-02 ┆ D     ┆ 5     │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ D     ┆ 2     │
│ 2024-01-04 ┆ D     ┆ -4    │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Now, running exactly the same code with `n` = 3:

```
df_piv = df.pivot(values='value',index='date',columns='label')
labels = df['label'].unique()
num = 3

def calc(df_calc, l):
    df_calc = df_calc.select(l).sum_horizontal()
    return ['+'.join(sorted(l)), df_calc.min(), df_calc.max()]

res = pl.DataFrame(
    data = [calc(df_piv, l) for l in itertools.combinations(labels, num)],
    schema = ['literal','min','max']
)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ literal ┆ min ┆ max │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A+B+D   ┆ -3  ┆ 9   │
│ A+C+D   ┆ -2  ┆ 9   │
│ A+B+C   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ B+C+D   ┆ -1  ┆ 5   │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    pl.concat([
    sm_df.lazy()
    .join(
        df.lazy().filter(pl.col('label')>label[0]), 
        on='date'
        )
    .select(
        literal = pl.lit(f"{label[0]}+")+pl.col('label_right'),
        value = pl.col('value') + pl.col('value_right')
        )
    for label, sm_df in df.partition_by('label', as_dict=True).items()
    ])
    .group_by('literal')
    .agg(
        min=pl.col('value').min(),
        max=pl.col('value').max()
    )
    .collect()
    )
```

The first thing this does (even though it's in the middle line at the end of the `for` line) is to partition the df by label. For each of those partitions, it joins to the rows of the rest of the df, by date, where the label is greater than the current label. It does that lazily so that the concat will run in parallel. It then groups by the new label, called "literal", and takes the min/max.